# Переход на сцену на определенные координаты

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне необходимо, чтобы объект появлялся на карте в разных местах в зависимости от того, с какой стороны на нее заходит персонаж. Скрипт прикреплен к объекту, который необходимо перенести на новую сцену.
Код вида `SceneManager.LoadScene(6);
          transform.position = new Vector3(-31.5f, 24f, 0f);` по какой-то причине не работает, объясните, пожалуйста, почему и приведите пример работающего скрипта

Comment: "не работает", приведите, пожалуйста, пример. Игры - это слишком комплексные системы, которые нельзя вот так просто отдебажить и силой мысли понять проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы на твоем месте создал несколько пустых обьектов в нужных местах, прикрепил бы к этим местам лейбочки (Game object Icons) и перемещал бы обьект копируя трансформ.позишн одного из этих обьектов. Это все делать после лоада сцены на моменте инициализации твоего монстра.

Это даст возможность не прописывать вручную позиции, а редактировать позиции визуально и исключает всякого рода неточности и ошибки программиста. Да и вообще Левел-дизайн нужно абстрагировать по-возможности от програмного кода.

Answer (score 1):

Как удалось нагуглить: после загрузки новой сцены дальнейший код перестаёт выполняться. Первое, что приходит на ум для вашей реализации: перед переходом на новую сцену сохранить позицию объекта в какой-нибудь статической переменной, а в новой сцене в каком-нибудь скрипте добавить что-то вроде:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
}

void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
{
    object.transfrom.position = someClass.oldStaticPosition;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
}
```

Это всё, естественно, псевдокод, приведённый просто для понимания.