# C# как добавить GameObject в код

Tags: c#

Я делаю игру в юнити, сделал спавн объектов в случайных координатах, которые я задаю. За объект который я спавню отвечает `public GameObject hazard;`. Проблема в том, что я могу добавить только один объект для этого кода.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы я мог добавить еще несколько объектов в код?

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hazard;
    public Vector3 spawnValues;
    public int hazardCount;
    public float spawnWait;
    public float startWait;
    public float waveWait;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++) 

            {
                Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), spawnValues.y, spawnValues.z);
                Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;

                Instantiate(hazard, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.5f, spawnWait));
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);

    }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переход на сцену на определенные координаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934997/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b)

Comment: а что мешает написать `public GameObject hazard1, hazard2;` или объявить массив геймобжектов

Comment: @trollingchar а как добавить массив?

Comment: `public GameObject[] hazards;` Вам нужно будет получше выучить основы C#.